# Accelerometer and Gyroscope Sensor

Tags: c#

I read in almost every articles that accelerometer is suitable for long term and gyro is for short term. But i couldn't able to get the technical reason behind this. Or in other words why it is said like that?

Any Help Appreciated...

Comment: I think [this article](http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/faq-whats-the-difference) sums it up nicely: `Accelerometers are right in the long term but wrong (noisy) in the short term. Gyros are right in the short term but wrong (drifiting) in the long term. You need both--each to calibrate the other--to be right all the time.`

Comment: Both do different readings. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope

Comment: Thanks fvu, Gandarez......

Comment: I got answer for gyro but not yet clear in the case of Accel.Help me out to be clear in accel....